# excelvba selenium cannot get html address

Tags: html, selenium

I have a problem with my html page below. because the page is encrypted; I have uploaded a screenshot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GW5ui.png)

I want to get the text in the 1st field.unfortunately, it doesn't come apart from the text in the 2nd field.

```
<div class="col-sm-4" id="anneAdi">
<i class="feather icon-eye-off f-20 bak2" data-id="0" data-bak="anneAdi"></i>
<img src="/Common/bitMapResimGoster.aspx?BitMapResim=&nbsp;:&nbsp;SEVİM"></div>
```

I want to write **SEVİM** in excel cell

<'elementler = baglan.FindElementByCss("#anneAdi > img").Attribute("src")>

<'elementler = baglan.FindElementByCss("img").Attribute("src")>

Formula result:     %C2%A0:%C2%A0SEV%C4%B0M

like. I tried constantly but it didn't work.
sorry for my broken english.I'm waiting for your help. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`%C2%A0:%C2%A0SEV%C4%B0M` If this is your problem, then you know that this is how it is encoded perhaps, because of the empty spaces that are there in the img src: `/Common/bitMapResimGoster.aspx?BitMapResim= : SEVİM`. Note that there are spaces after `BitMapResim`, and because of that the output shows like that.
[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CA81l.png)

A snippet from W3Schools (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

> URL Encoding (Percent Encoding)
>
> URL encoding converts characters into a format that can be transmitted
> over the Internet.
>
> URLs can only be sent over the Internet using the ASCII character-set.
>
> Since URLs often contain characters outside the ASCII set, the URL has
> to be converted into a valid ASCII format.
>
> URL encoding replaces unsafe ASCII characters with a "%" followed by
> two hexadecimal digits.
>
> URLs cannot contain spaces. URL encoding normally replaces a space
> with a plus (+) sign or with %20.

Comment: nice explanation. but how can i print to excel cell...

Comment: I am not sure how it is done with VBA, but maybe you have to force it into a cell as a value? I mean, you have the variable elementler which you have to insert into a cell, like `wb[sheet1].C1.value=elementler`. I am not sure of the exact syntax here

Comment: Common/bitMapResimGoster.aspx?BitMapResim=%C2%A0:%C2%A0AY%C5%9EE    unfortunately this is the result

Comment: `BitMapResim=%C2%A0:%C2%A0AY%C5%9EE` decodes to `BitMapResim= : AYŞE`.  Do you have any other element with id attribute `annaAdi`?  What you are getting is an utf-8 encode/decode norm, but besides that do you have any `src` with `BitMapResim= : AYŞE`? If yes, then that is what is being fetched. Moreover it is not the `AYSE` per se that is having those special char, it is the spaces before and after the colon and also the `Ş`. These spaces and the `Ş` are what are encoded into %etc etc, which is completely fine and it is the norm, if I may say.

Comment: exactly. result AYŞE. : the following post, I need it. There are 500 pieces of data like this. You need to save them in excel. another example. Common/bitMapResimGoster.aspx?BitMapResim=%C2%A0:%C2%A0NAR%C4%B0NG%C3%9CL

Comment: I am not sure what you want exactly. The query you originally asked has been answered. If you have 500 of such links and you want them to print to excel, then you can loop through and increase the cell for each iteration and print the value there.